# Why is a unary numeral system bijective?

Tags: number-theory, peano-axioms

In [this treatment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unary_numeral_system) of unary numeral system, it is called "bijective base-1 numeral system." I understand bijective from functions, but why is it used here? Also, the article says the Peano as well as Church numbers are unary numeral systems. Peano's system is based on repeating a successor function. Yes, I suppose a Peano number resembles tally marks. Basically, I'm not understanding the use of unary nor bijective here.

Comment: Bijective, because there's a one-one correspondence between positive integers and the notations representing them. Unary, because each positive integer takes one more symbol than the preceding.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Good for bijective, but for unary, is Peano's successor function unary?

Comment: Isn't it? If $R$ is the representation of $n-1$, then $SR$ is the representation of $n$, right? So, one more symbol.

Comment: click the [bijective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijective_numeration) link in the article you are referencing. It links to "Bijective_numeration"

Comment: @GerryMyerson I think "unary", because there is only one symbol (one digit), in contrast to binary (2 symbols) , ternary (3 symbols), decimal(10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unary simply means it is a base-1 notational system (only one digit), as opposed to binary (2 digits, "0" and "1), or decimal (10 digits, "0" … "9").

The pop-up note on "bijective" in the linked article says:

> Bijective numeration is any numeral system in which every non-negative integer can be represented in exactly one way using a finite string of digits.

For instance the value 4 can be represented as "1111", and only as "1111";
and similarly the representation "1111" matches the value 4 and only the value 4.

That property holds for all values, and makes it bijective.

Comment: Bijective you nailed. But I do believe the unary part does mean unary operators/functions as well. Wikipedia's Unary function article gives Peano's successor function as an example of a unary function -- which is a bit confusing, since mostly we're familiar with unary operators, e.g., logical not or a dash in front to make a number negative, etc.